# addFieldToFilter() And Condition in magento2

Tags: magento2, database, filter

I need to filter values based on and condition in my custom table

my tablename `Testing`

```
 +-------------+--------------------+--------------------+
 | customer_id | customergroup      | customeremails     |
 +-------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

if **customergroup** and **customeremails** same means I dont add this value

so, I put this condition:

```
   $multiselectupdate =$multiselect->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('customergroup', "'eq'=>$categoryname")
                                ->addFieldToFilter('customeremails',"'eq'=>$mail");
```

But, its not working for Suggest me How set **And Condition** in **addFieldToFilter**() method.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try with below code,

```
$multiselectupdate =$multiselect->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('customergroup', ['eq' => $categoryname])
                                ->addFieldToFilter('customeremails',['eq' => $mail]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try following way:

```
$multiselect->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('customergroup', array('eq'=>$categoryname))
->addFieldToFilter('customeremails',array('eq'=>$mail));
```

No need to assign new variable again.

Debug:

```
echo $multiselect->count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for you to understand how Magento 2 use query operators to filter with **addFieldToFilter**

[click](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/addattributetofilter/)

or simple in your case:

```
$multiselectupdate->addFieldToFilter('customergroup', ['eq' => "$categoryname"]);
```