# Magento 2 : AND condition in addAttributeToFilter not giving desired result

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, collection, custom-options

According to answer to [this related question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144629/addfieldtofilter-and-cndition-in-magento2)
the AND condition in addAttributeToFilter is added by adding consecutive addAttributeToFilter so my statement is something like;

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array(
                    array('nin' => $brands)
                ))->addAttributeToFilter('warehouse1', array(
                    array('nin' => 0)
                ))->addAttributeToFilter('warehouse4', array(
                    array('nin' => 0)
                )); // I want product to be excluded when both warehouse1 and warehouse4 is 0
```

As in the code above I need the product to be removed from collection when both "warehouse1" and "warehouse4" are simultaneously 0 but instead the code is first filtering collection based on "warehouse1" and then the filtered collection is filtered again for "warehouse4".
   As a result I am also excluding products which have 0 for "warehouse1" but not a 0 for "warehouse4".
Please help me resolve this.

**EDIT:**

The answer by @Murtuza Zabuawala worked for me, it was not working before as some of the attributes had null for them even though they were supposed to be 0 by default. 
 However, this does not answer the core question of how to add **AND** to `addAttributeToFilter` but nonetheless I am going to award the bounty.

Comment: is warehouse1 and warehouse4 is type of select or multiselect

Comment: They are text fields

Comment: check updated answer and let me know if you still face any problem

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Your updated answer applies OR condition between the addAttributetoFilter  and is not giving desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try below code for and condition in two or more attribute

```
    $_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array(
                array('nin' => $brands)
            ))->addAttributeToFilter(
              array(
                array('attribute' => 'warehouse1', 'neq' => 0),
                array('attribute' => 'warehouse4', 'neq' => 0),
            ));
```

**Edit**

According TO your answer I have Improved your answer

```
$cloned_collection = clone $_productCollection;
$product_ids = $cloned_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('warehouse1', array(
                array('eq'=> '0'),
                array('null' => 'this_value_doesnt_matter'),
                array('eq' =>'0.00')    
            ))->addAttributeToFilter('warehouse4', array(
                array('eq'=> '0'),
                array('null' => 'this_value_doesnt_matter'),
                array('eq' =>'0.00')    
            ))->getAllIds();

$_productCollection =  $_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => $product_ids));
```

**Edit2**

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array(
                array('nin' => $brands)
            ))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('warehouse1',array('neq' => ''))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('warehouse4',array('neq' => ''))  //check wareHouse != null and add innerJoin
        ->getSelect()->where("at_warehouse1 <> 0 AND at_warehouse4 <> 0 ");
```

Comment: This gives the same result as my code.

Comment: @Neo ... this is the solution. It should work.

Comment: @AlexConstantinescu This applies an OR condition ..

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala actually i am filtering this result in list.phtml so, if I am using ids to filter it is filtering the result for just current page, so not useful for my case.

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Also your answer also not improves much as it also does the same thing in i.e filter in two steps

Comment: @neo you can filter this in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` class

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Thanks for updated answer, I will check and update if it works for me

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala say my attribute to filter was warehouse4/varying-data/that/matters/ and i had results returned like warehouse1/varying-data/that/matters/how would i filter so it filters based on the first X characters of an attribute

Comment: I dont understand your query @John

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala understandable, it turns out i was looking for the LIKE filter, i was trying to filter by the first couple letters of a string, ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array( 
                array('like' => '%'.$query.'%'), //like needle
                array('like' => $query.'%') // starts with needle));

Comment: @John , I think its already answered at here, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11082/filtering-results-using-like

Comment: Ah, yes that's what i found to do it, thank you Murtuza!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you'd need `warehouse1 != 0 OR warehouse4 != 0`.

Or conditions are combined like this:

```
addFieldToFilter(['field1', 'field2'], [$condition1, $condition2]);
```

So in your case it is:

```
addAttributeToFilter(
    ['warehouse1', 'warehouse4'],
    [['neq' => 0], ['neq' => 0]],
);
```

**Update:** This syntax to combine OR conditions does not work anymore in Magento 2. Th correct way has been described by @MurtuzaZabuawala in his original answer:

```
addAttributeToFilter(
    [
        [
            'attribute' => 'warehouse1',
            'neq' => 0
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'warehouse4',
            'neq' => 0
        ],
    ]
);
```

This results in `(warehouse1 != 0 OR warehouse4 != 0)`, which is the condition you need according to your description.

Comment: First of all above code gave a parse error on first run because of comma for second array , after fixing that it gives error Warning: Illegal string offset 'attribute' in Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php on line 362  . Please atleast post working code.

Comment: Again, I need an AND condition, is that so hard to understand?
This community is total garbage.

Comment: With personal insults you won't get better help, that's for sure. You need a negated AND which is equivalent to OR : `! ( A && B) == !A || !B`. Basic boolean logic.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround though it is not elegant in any way and I still think there should be a way to do it in one step,
Instead of filtering and removing the 0 in the first step itself I have made a collection which has both attributes 0 and it works as it is applying filter over the filter before [as I have explained in question].Then I am getting all skus from this collection to filter the required collection like below ;

```
$cloned_collection = clone $_productCollection;
$cloned_collection = $cloned_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('warehouse1', array(
                    array('eq'=> '0'),
                    array('null' => 'this_value_doesnt_matter'),
                    array('eq' =>'0.00')    
                ))->addAttributeToFilter('warehouse4', array(
                    array('eq'=> '0'),
                    array('null' => 'this_value_doesnt_matter'),
                    array('eq' =>'0.00')    
                ))->getData();
                for($i=0;$i<count($cloned_collection);$i++){
                    $skuArray[$i] = $cloned_collection[$i]['sku']; 
                }
$_productCollection =  $_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('nin' => $skuArray));
```

Please let me know if someone has a better working solution.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: please check EDIT2