# Filter product collection with nested OR/AND statements

Tags: magento2, database, eav, addattributetofilter

I want to make a query as below

```
 WHERE manageStock = 0 OR (manageStock = 1 AND productStatus != 0) OR (manageStock = 1 AND backorderStatus = 1)
```

but I can't use **$collection->getSelect()->where()** because these are EAV attributes so I need to use **addAttributeToFilter()** for them.

Please help to use the above in Magento's way.

Comment: check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/188685/91726) answer.

Comment: that didn't help unfortunately @AbdulSamadAbbasi